# Counting the number of ways 6 blocks are organized but they aren't all distinct

Tags: combinatorics

There are 2 green blocks, 2 red blocks, 1 orange block, and 1 blue block. If the blocks are stacked on top of each other vertically, how many different stacks of 3 blocks can you make?

I can't figure the solution to this. I think you start it by using $^6P_3$ but I don't know where to go after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't go after a general formula, but do a direct counting instead.

We can choose and stack three different colors in $4\cdot3\cdot 2=24$ ways. Furthermore we can choose two equals in $2$ ways, then a third in $3$ ways, and we can put the single one at $3$ different places, giving $2\cdot3\cdot3=18$ different stacks of this type. The final answer then is $42$.